# vba to search a list and colour code matches based on a contents list.

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro that can search through a list of data and colour code the entries based on the data from a contents list.

eg search data in column A if corresponds to column B (contents) then colour code the entry in column A to match the pre colour coded data in column B.

I need this to loop through around 1000 entries.

Thanks in advance.
Andy

Comment: Record a macro and then change the code accordingly using the appropriate if-clauses.
The recorded macro will show you the VBA code needed to switch the active cell etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to encourage you, because **you did not follow the site rules that say to research and attempt a solution before asking a quesiton, and share what you have already tried**. That is probably why others have given your question a negative rating.

However, you did enough thinking about the parameters of your problem, that I suspect you may have tried something before composing this question, and I'm granting you the benefit of the doubt. Here is a possible solution, if by "pre colour coded data" you mean the interior of the cell.

Change the Constants at the top to match the column and header row of your data.

If the pre colour coding of your data is something other than the interior settings I've used, you can take Marty McVry's advice of using the macro recorder to determine which settings you are changing and incorporate them in this code (where the `With rCell.Interior` code is).

```
Sub MatchColor()

Const sColumnID As String = "A"
Const iHeaderID As Integer = 1

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rColumn As Range

Set rColumn = Range(sColumnID & iHeaderID, Range(sColumnID & iHeaderID).End(xlDown))

For Each rCell In rColumn

    If rCell.Value = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        With rCell.Interior
            .Pattern = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Pattern
            .PatternColorIndex = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.PatternColorIndex
            .ThemeColor = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ThemeColor
            .TintAndShade = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.TintAndShade
            .PatternTintAndShade = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.PatternTintAndShade
        End With
    End If

Next rCell

End Sub
```